# GLMatrixStackOverflowExceptionwith SceneManager

Tags: android, andengine, stack-overflow

I am developing a scene manager with AndEngine and am getting a GLMatrixStackOverflowExceptionerror:

*E/AndroidRuntime(1906): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 130
E/AndroidRuntime(1906): org.andengine.opengl.util.GLMatrixStack$GLMatrixStackOverflowException
E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at org.andengine.opengl.util.GLMatrixStack.glPushMatrix(GLMatrixStack.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at org.andengine.opengl.util.GLState.pushProjectionGLMatrix(GLState.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:1348)
E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:1585)
E/AndroidRuntime(1906):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:259)*

2 Classes below: `GameActivity` and `SceneManager`
The problem occurs in `GameActivity` on this line:
`sceneManager.setCurrentScene(SceneType.MENU); // ???`

What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.ITimerCallback;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.scenemanager.SceneManager;
import com.example.scenemanager.SceneManager.SceneType;


/**
 * Example of using a SceneManager with GLES2 AnchorCenter
 */
public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    Scene mScene;

    protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    BitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
    ITextureRegion playerTextureRegion;
    SceneManager sceneManager;
    Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        mCamera = new Camera (0,0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        EngineOptions engineOptions = (new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT) , mCamera));
        return engineOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws IOException {

        // mEngine is from superclass
        sceneManager = new SceneManager(this, mEngine, mCamera);
        sceneManager.loadSplashSceneResources();

        // let the game engine know we are done loading the resources we need
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws IOException {

        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(sceneManager.createSplashScene());
    }

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback)
        throws IOException {

    mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(3.0f, new ITimerCallback()  { // 3 seconds to load all stuff

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

            Log.d("onPopulateScene()", "onTimePassed()");

            // unregister so as only do this once
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);

            // done displaying splash, so go to menu
            sceneManager.loadMenuSceneResources();
            sceneManager.createMenuScene();

            mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

                @Override
                public void reset() { }

                @Override
                public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
                    Log.d("onPopulateScene()", "onUpdate()");
                    sceneManager.setCurrentScene(SceneType.MENU); // ???
                }
            });

        }
    })); 

    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}    
}

package com.example.scenemanager;

import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

public class SceneManager {

    private SceneType currentScene;
    private BaseGameActivity activity;
    private Engine engine;
    private Camera camera;

    private Scene splashScene;
    private Scene menuScene;
    private Scene gameScene;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas splashTextureAtlas;
    private TextureRegion splashTextureRegion;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas menuTextureAtlas;
    private TextureRegion menuTextureRegion;

    private float xPosition;
    private float yPosition;

    public enum SceneType
    {
        SPLASH,
        MENU,
        GAME
    }

    /**
     * constructor
     * 
     * @param baseGameActivity
     * @param engine
     * @param camera
     */
    public SceneManager(BaseGameActivity baseGameActivity, Engine engine, Camera camera) {

        this.activity = baseGameActivity;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.camera = camera;       

        xPosition = camera.getWidth()/2; 
        yPosition = camera.getHeight()/2;

    }

    public void loadSplashSceneResources() {

        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        splashTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.activity.getTextureManager(),256, 256);
        splashTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(splashTextureAtlas, this.activity, "splash.png", 0, 0);
        splashTextureAtlas.load();

    }

    public void loadMenuSceneResources() {

        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        menuTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.activity.getTextureManager(),256, 256);
        menuTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(menuTextureAtlas, this.activity, "menu.png", 0, 0);
        menuTextureAtlas.load();
    }

    public void loadGameSceneResources() {

    }

    public Scene createSplashScene() {

        // Set background color and add the splash image
        splashScene = new Scene();
        splashScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 1, 0)); // green
        Sprite splash = new Sprite(0, 0, splashTextureRegion, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        splash.setPosition(xPosition, yPosition);
        splashScene.attachChild(splash);

        return splashScene;
    }

    public Scene createMenuScene() {

        menuScene = new Scene();
        menuScene.setBackground(new Background(0,0,0));
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite (0, 0, menuTextureRegion, engine .getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        sprite.setPosition(xPosition, yPosition);
        menuScene.attachChild(menuScene);
        return menuScene;

    }

    public void createGameScene() {     

        //Create the Main Game Scene and set background colour to blue
        gameScene = new Scene();
        gameScene.setBackground(new Background(0, 0, 1));
    }

    public SceneType getCurrentScene() {
        return currentScene;

    }

    public void setCurrentScene(SceneType scene) {
    if (scene != currentScene) {
        currentScene = scene;
        switch (scene)
        {
        case SPLASH:
            break;
        case MENU:
            engine.setScene(menuScene);
            break;
        case GAME:
            engine.setScene(gameScene);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }       
    }   
    }

}
```

Comment: you probably need to do that call to set the scene on the updateThread - search here for how to do that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've made changes on your suggestion (and updated the code in the original post reflecting this, in particular in `onPopulateScene()`), but still getting an error.

Comment: Found it. `menuScene.attachChild(sprite);`   If you put your comment in the form of an answer, I will accept, since it pointed me in right direction

Comment: +1 to you for figuring it out.